# Iterating & containers of smart pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, iterator, shared-ptr

I have a container of smart pointers to mutable objects.  I have to write two *for_each* loops, one for accessing the objects as read-only data and another for mutable data.  The compiler is telling me that `std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Object> >` is not the same as `std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<const Object> >`, note the `const`.

Here is my example code:

```
#include <vector>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include <iterator>

class Field_Interface
{ ; };
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Field_Interface> Ptr_Field_Interface;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const Field_Interface> Ptr_Const_Field_Interface;

struct Field_Iterator
  : std::input_iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Ptr_Field_Interface>
{
  // forward iterator methods & operators...
};

struct Const_Field_Iterator
  : std::input_iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Ptr_Const_Field_Interface>
{
  // forward iterator methods & operators...
};

struct Field_Functor
{
  virtual void operator()(const Ptr_Field_Interface&) = 0;
  virtual void operator()(const Ptr_Const_Field_Interface&) = 0;
};

class Record;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Record> Ptr_Record;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const Record> Ptr_Const_Record;

class Record_Base
{
  protected:
    virtual Field_Iterator beginning_field(void) = 0;
    virtual Field_Iterator ending_field(void) = 0;
    virtual Const_Field_Iterator const_beginning_field(void) = 0;
    virtual Const_Field_Iterator const_ending_field(void) = 0;

    void for_each(Field_Functor * p_functor)
    {
       Field_Iterator iter_begin(beginning_field());
       Field_Iterator iter_end(ending_field());
       for (; iter_begin != iter_end; ++ iter_begin)
       {
         (*p_functor)(*iter_begin);
       }
     }
};

class Record_Derived
{
public:
   typedef std::vector<Ptr_Field_Interface> Field_Container;
   typedef std::vector<Ptr_Record>          Record_Container;
private:
   Field_Container m_fields;
   Record_Container m_subrecords;
};
```

Given all the above details, how do I implement the pure abstract methods of `Record_Base` in `Record_Derived`?

I've tried:

- returning `m_fields.begin()`, which
  returns conversion errors (can't
  convert `std::vector<...> to
  Field_Iterator`)
- returning `&m_fields[0]`, which is
  dangerous, because it assumes stuff
  about the internals of `std::vector`.

*BTW, I'm not using `std::for_each` because I have to iterate over a container of fields **and** a container of sub-records.*

Comment: I'm curious, on what compiler are you getting the sample to compile at all? VC8 and GCC3/4 don't work.

Comment: @gf: I think he might be using STLPort, which still has the `std::forward_iterator` template for backward compatility with early drafts of the standard.

Comment: @gf, @Emile:  My bad, the identifier should be `std::forward_iterator_tag`.  I'm using MS Visual Studio 2008.  The example given most like won't compile as it is a stripped down version to show concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing resembles both the [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) patterns. Those two patterns mesh well together, so it seems you are on the right track.

To implement the composite pattern, assign the following roles (refer to Composite pattern UML diagram):

- Leaf -> `Field`
- Composite -> `Record`
- Component -> Abstract base class of `Field` and `Record` (can't think of a good name)

Component operations that are called on Composite types, are passed on recursively to all children (Leaves and other nested Composite types).

To implement the Visitor pattern, overload `operator()` in your functor classes for each Component subtype (Field and Record).

I recommend that you get a copy of the [*Design Patterns*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book by the "Gang of Four", which explains these concepts better and goes into much more detail than I possibly can.

Here is some sample code to whet your appetite:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/foreach.hpp"

class Field;
class Record;

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void operator()(Field& field) = 0;
    virtual void operator()(Record& field) = 0;
};

class Component
{
public:
    virtual bool isLeaf() const {return true;}
    virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor) = 0;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Component> ComponentPtr;

class Field : public Component
{
public:
    explicit Field(int value) : value_(value) {}
    void accept(Visitor& visitor) {visitor(*this);}
    int value() const {return value_;}

private:
    int value_;
};

class Record : public Component
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<ComponentPtr> Children;
    Record(int id) : id_(id) {}
    int id() const {return id_;}
    Children& children() {return children_;}
    const Children& children() const {return children_;}
    bool isLeaf() const {return false;}
    void accept(Visitor& visitor)
    {
        visitor(*this);
        BOOST_FOREACH(ComponentPtr& child, children_)
        {
            child->accept(visitor);
        }
    }

private:
    int id_;
    Children children_;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Record> RecordPtr;

struct OStreamVisitor : public Visitor
{
    OStreamVisitor(std::ostream& out) : out_(out) {}
    void operator()(Field& field) {out_ << "field(" << field.value() << ") ";}
    void operator()(Record& rec) {out_ << "rec(" << rec.id() << ") ";}
    std::ostream& out_;
};

int main()
{
    RecordPtr rec(new Record(2));
        rec->children().push_back(ComponentPtr(new Field(201)));
        rec->children().push_back(ComponentPtr(new Field(202)));
    RecordPtr root(new Record(1));
        root->children().push_back(ComponentPtr(new Field(101)));
        root->children().push_back(rec);

    OStreamVisitor visitor(std::cout);
    root->accept(visitor);
}
```

In Record, you may want to provide methods for manipulating/accessing children, instead of returning a reference to the underlying children vector.

Comment: @Emile:  Thanks, I'm familiar with Visitor, I'll refresh my memory with the Composite pattern.  An idea struck me:  Simplify `Record_Base` to *container*, and convert to standard container idioms so that `std::for_each` will work on the `Record_Base` container.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to write an own iterator when you use a common container type. Writing an own iterator makes sense when you write an own container. However, when you are planning to write a custom iterator have a look at the [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide `std::vector` and its iterators from the user, then you will need to provide polymorphic iterators to go along with your polymorphic `RecordBase` container. Check out [`any_iterator`](http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html) from the Adobe ASL library. [These](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2001/02/8974.php) [links](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/polycontainer.aspx) may also be helpful.

However, instead of going to all that trouble, you should consider using the Composite and Visitor patterns in your design. See my other answer.